# Excel formula to extract key information to another cell/column for review

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

In Excel I have cells containing varied information into paragraphs.

As this is just an extract of the actual source material a way to format this to achieve what im looking for would be ideal. (take into account that information required is inbetween brackets)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have Excel 365, you can combine `IF`, `IFERROR`, `TEXTAFTER`, `TEXTBEFORE`, `TEXTJOIN` and `CHAR` functions to obtain the result. Assuming your data are in columns A, try the following in column B:

```
=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),TRUE,IFERROR(IF(LEFT(A1:A22,1)="[",TEXTBEFORE(TEXTAFTER(A1:A22,"_",1),"_",1),""),""))
```

- `IF`: to check that the first character is `[`. If yes, extract the word using TEXTAFTER and TEXTBEFORE functions
- `IFERROR`: In case of error, show empty string
- `CHAR(10)`: inserts a new line between cells/words
- `TEXTJOIN`: concatenates the strings/words and ignores empty cells

[image]

Comment: Yes I'm using the latest version of Excel, could I then redirect column b to be added all in one cell all together without the gaps, take into account my code above is merely an extract, meaning (there are a lot more) there would be a lot of gaps in-between.

Comment: What do you mean by gaps? Empty cells? Are the data in a single cell?

Comment: Empty cells in between paragraphs of data, and the data itself isn't as shown above it's divided by line in different cells, unsure if that would still make it work. How can I expand therefore your command to work on the whole spreadsheet say, 2000 blocks of data. https://imgur.com/a/nyFv1OO hope this helps you, in this case extract alerts and reporting, into a tidy column with all others. After that is there a way to remove duplicates from that column?

Comment: Change the formula to `=TEXTBEFORE(TEXTAFTER(A1,"_",1),"_",1)`. Then drag it down to fill the cells below.

Comment: Since they are in different cells (see image), is there a way of putting them all in one like you did in your screenshot?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/3opG2EG this is my issue see, it works but how do I format it to work for me?

Comment: The inputs are on the same cells on my image) because I copied them from the example you gave on the OP and assumed the space was a separation to go to the next cell. If my they should not be in the same cell, the formula is still correct. So, the question is what part should be on the same cell: the input or the output (result)?

Comment: Ideally the output because the input (raw data) is in different cells.

Comment: Then I will need to review the formula.

Comment: Thanks, much help :)

Comment: @3Cubed I have change the formula. See edit.